# Error de consulta php nativo

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb

tengo el siguiente codigo.

```
$dbconnection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname)
     if (!$dbconnection) {
  die('Connect Error: ' . mysqli_connect_errno());
  }


$query = "INSERT INTO `user1` (`id`, `name`, `in`, `out`, `dialcode`)VALUES ('', '$CONTACT', '$IN', '$OUT', '$
    $result = mysqli_query($dbconnection, $query)
    or die("Couldn't execute SQL query on AsteriDex table." .   mysqli_error_list($query)) ;
```

Al usar esta parte del codigo tengo este error.

Warning: mysqli_error_list() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /var/www/myroot/asteridex4/admin.php on line 88
Couldn't execute SQL query on AsteriDex table.

No se el por que del error, tengo otras sentencias en este formulario que funcionan con la misma conexion, pero este insert no funciona.

Saludos.

Comment: Como puedes observar en la [doc. oficial](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error-list.php) el método `mysqli_error_list` recibe como argumento a la conexión y tu le estás pasando la *consulta*, realiza ese cambio y nos avisas

Comment: Gracias, no encontre el metodo, el error era que no habia necesidad de incluir el campo id en el insert, ya que es autoincrement, lo quite y listo.